# What similar expression can I use for 'to find out' in the given context?

Tags: word-usage, word-request

> Is that store open today?
>   I don't know, you should call X **to find out**.

Is the expression *to find out* correct? What similar expression can I use in place of *to find out*?

Answer (score 2):

*Find out,* which means **to learn a piece of information,** is the best verb to use here.

In its place, other expressions would be: *and ask, and ask them, and/to check, to be sure,* or *to make sure.*

Answer (score 0):

In this context we can assume that the person aiming to find out will be talking to a person on the other end of the phone (as opposed to a service)

Thus, some alternatives:

> I don't know, you should call X **to ask**.
>
> I don't know, you should call X **then you'll know**.
>
> I don't know, you should call X **then you'll find out**.

Though in this context these wouldn't make much sense without reconstructing the sentence, the following are good replacements for "to find out":

> Discover (You can call X and discover)
>
> See (If you call X you will see)
>
> Unearth (If you find the directory you might unearth it)
>
> Come across (You might come across it in the directory)
>
> Get (You can get that information from the Internet)

You have a wealth of choice :)

**EDIT:** Shawn however does make the best point, that what you have already is the best phrase to use in your example. :)